# How to include Voice Matching features in voice apps? (Alexa/Google Home)

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

I'm wondering if it's possible to use the voice matching features in Alexa skills or Google actions.

For example, if the user is trying to log in to my skill, and someone else (that's not the user) says the PIN, it will recognize the voice and deny the access.

Is it possible in Alexa/Google Home? I didn't find any documentations/explanations on this.

Comment: Like using voice profiles or something

Comment: I can't speak for Alexa, but as far Google Assistant is concerned, voice match is possible on devices, but not in development. You can link up to 6 people’s voices with Voice Match to a single speaker or Smart Display, docs here (https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/9071681?hl=en). Developers can't access a user's voice, however - only the text translation of what a user said.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to include voice matching features in voice apps. When you turn on
Voice Match, you can teach Google Assistant to recognize your voice so it can verify
who you are before it gives you [personal results](https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/7684543). You can turn on Voice Match for a
home or specific Assistant-enabled devices, like a speaker, Smart Display, or Smart
Clock. Up to 6 people can turn on Voice Match for one home in the Google Home
app. More information about how to enable this feature can be found [here](https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/9071681?hl=en).